# oracle view all procedures and function inside of package

Tags: sql, oracle

I can execute a procedure inside of a package, but I would like to be able to view all the procedures and functions inside of this package as there are more. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all in the ALL_SOURCE table.

```
DESC ALL_SOURCE;
```

For the package spec:

```
select text
from all_source
where type = 'PACKAGE'
and name = 'YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME'
order by line asc;
```

For the package body:

```
select text
from all_source
where type = 'PACKAGE BODY'
and name = 'YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME'
order by line asc;
```

Comment: Why `order by line DESC`?

Comment: D'OH!  I Meant ASC.  I guess I had desc on the brain from the DESCribe statement. :-/  I amended my post.  thanks for bringing this up.